# android: why can't I reference my layout (perhaps after moving it)?

Tags: android

With some stackoverflow trolling I've been able to get a an android popup view working, but I tried to move the layout and it doesn't work now. I have a popup view in res/layout-keysexposed-qwerty/login_popup2.xml.

Its layout contains the following:

```
android:id="@+id/login_popup2"
```

Here's where I try to reference it inside of an Activity:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
android.view.View popview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_popup2, null, false);
```

And that fails with the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
```

How do I reference a layout in this manner? I thought it was working when I had it in `res/layout-keysexposed/` but I moved it, did a clean project in Eclipse, and even stopped and started my Android

(edit1)

Here's the class definition from R.java:

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_view=0x7f030000;
    public static final int login_popup2=0x7f030001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The id of a layout file is its filename and directory, not including the .xml extention.  Your id there is the id of some element in the layout.  Ignore the fact that it may be called LinearLayout or RelativeLayout-  those are both views.

Comment: So id is a red herring- but isn't it still a R.layout.(something)?

Comment: Yes, since you should put your layouts in the layout folder.  If trying to reference a view you just do R.id.(something), as there is no folder for ids (they auto-generate).  I'd try doing a clean in Eclipse if you're having id problems, Eclipse won't always generate everything unless you start fresh.

Comment: if I use R.layout.login_popup2, which is in my R.java, it fails. If I add an idname and use that, it fails with 'type not valid'. I think I'll try adding a view to `res/layout-keysexposed` instead of `res/layout-keysexposed-qwerty` and see if it works there.

Answer (score 0):

If you closer R.java closely you will find that layout class contains the reference to the layout with the name of the xml file. So, you should be using R.layout..

Comment: I looked at R.java and R.layout.login_popup2 is there. So it should be referenced correctly. But obviously it isn't working.